# How to protect the control environment of my web application?

Tags: web-application, wifi, content-security-policy, persona

I am developing a web application and want to do its setup and control using my personal notebook.

However, the following topics concern me:

1) Enter the platform (includes the login in the control panel of my application) that hosts my site.
* This platform does not have the option of 2-step verification.

2) Mozilla thunderbird webmail service.
* The webmail has been configured with ssl security.

Considering that I use a wi-fi modem, what risks are I subject to?
How to make this environment as safe as possible?